# Routing error in LWIP when i try to connect to server

Tags: c, iot, ethernet, lwip, stm32cubeide

Im trying to use LWIP to connect to a remote host but im failing and getting a routing error when i try to connect.

I've tryed a few diffrent setups using netconn, tcp and even udp, but all setups fail when im trying to connect. So i think im missing something rather important in the setup before calling connect, but i cant figur out whats wrong.

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  Print("USART init ok\n");
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  Print("USB pcd init ok\n");
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  Print("LWIP init ok\n");

  struct tcp_pcb * tcp_client = {0};
  tcp_client = tcp_new();


  if(tcp_client != 0)
  {
      Print("tcp_new ok\n");
      err_t error = {0};
      error = tcp_bind(tcp_client, IP_ADDR_ANY);

      if(error == ERR_OK)
      {
          Print("tcp_bind ok\n");
          err_t errorConnect = {0};
          struct ip4_addr remoteIP;
          IP4_ADDR(&remoteIP, 192, 168, 127, 250);
          errorConnect = tcp_connect(tcp_client, &remoteIP, 4002, tcpConnect);

          if(errorConnect == ERR_OK)
          {
              Print("tcp_connect ok\n");
          }
          else
          {
// I end up here with ERR_RTE as a result
              Print("Error: tcp_connect \n");
          }
      }
      else
      {
          Print("Error: tcp_bind\n");
      }
  }
  else
  {
      Print("Error: tcp_new faild\n");
  }

  Print("DONE!\n\n");

  while (1)
  {

  }
}
```

Im using STM32CubeIDE and LWIP has been added as a middleware, 
The card im using is a ST nucleo F746ZG

the card is connected straight to my computer, and i can see it connect in my networksettings on my computer. So some form of negotiation is happening.

Comment: How is the system connected to the network? Where is the host you try to connect to located? On the same network? On a different network but still "in the same building"? Somewhere on a remote network?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now by setting up local IP address and netmask, I thougt  IPADDR_ANY was the way to go, but i needed to set a specific ipaddress for it to succceed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect like in following example using netconn

```
struct netconn *nc;
ip_addr_t remote_ip;
ip4addr_aton("192.168.127.250", &remote_ip);

nc = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
volatile err_t res;
res = netconn_connect(nc, &remote_ip, 4002);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up local IP address and netmask could get it working. But the root cause of the ERR_RTE (Routing problem) is that the TCP/IP stack has not finished setting up the ip/netmask/gw before netconn_connect is called. That should be a err because the ip/netmask/gw are probably empty at that time.

The solution would be delay netconn_connect() until proper IP configuration is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem which I haven't been able to solve, although I am on a different device..
Have you tried changing

```
error = tcp_bind(tcp_client, IP_ADDR_ANY);
```

to

```
error = tcp_bind(tcp_client, IP_ADDR_ANY, 4002);
```

Otherwise as stated [here](https://lwip.fandom.com/wiki/Raw/TCP#Active_connection)

***If the port is specified as zero, the function selects an available port.***